# How to get the tracking job URL with sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, sparklyr

When I launch a Spark or Hive job and look at the logs, I can see a line telling me how to track the job execution

```
INFO  : The url to track the job: https://host.com:8090/proxy/application_1544050868879_3083/
```

However, when I start a job with Sparklyr, I don't see any information about the logging url.

Is there a way to get the tracking url for a sparklyr job, while the job is still running?